# Is it possible to migrate from ASP.NET Core MVC to ASP.NET MVC architecture?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, asp.net-core, server, migration

I have an application running on ASP.NET Core MVC. I am trying to deploy the application on Godaddy Windows based shared server, however it seems that ASP.NET Core applications cannot run straight away.

So I tried to upload a sample ASP.NET MVC project to Godaddy and it worked fine. I was wondering if I can migrate from ASP.NET Core MVC to ASP.NET MVC structure to deploy and run my existing application. Or if there is any workaround that can be done to run the core application itself.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Asp.net core application can run on Godaddy server. You did not mention what type of hosting it is. On shared hosting they install .net core as discussed here: https://uk.godaddy.com/community/Plesk-Hosting/Does-asp-net-core-is-supported-by-godaddy-on-shared-hosting/td-p/131238

If it is a VPS hosting then you can install it by yourself (download from Microsoft's site).

Moving from Asp.net core to MVC will be a backward move.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response mate. The server I am using is a shared hosting server. I have rented it for a year for my university project.

Comment: I have placed all the files in the folder but when i try to access the site from the browser it say Future home of something quite cool however my asp,net core application doesnot run

Comment: Is there any error message that you see? Have you contacted their support team? Make sure they have installed .net core bundled on their server. Basically there are few error that I encounter when deployed .net core, you can refer to this post https://windowswebhostingreview.com/troubleshoot-403-error-when-publishing-asp-net-core/ and https://windowswebhostingreview.com/asp-net-core-hosting-3-simple-steps-to-fix-502-5-error-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: @seeratmahajan if it says "Future home of something quite cool" that means it is loading some files. Did you delete the default files? Also on shared hosting the .net core framework should be available. Which version of .net core are you using?